# Creating a database of many products

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, inventory

I am creating an inventory app currently for iPhone using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) for companies to keep track of all of their tools, supplies, inventory. Now I'd like to allow for the user/company when adding a new item to their database for them to have the option to search from a pre-made database of items such as for a construction company when adding a simple Dewalt Drill Battery to their inventory would search the pre-made database for "Dewalt #DC9096 18V XRP 2.4A Battery" or an office would search for pencils by brand/serial number/name. I am looking for a simple way to make a database or even a table containing multiple brands products including their prices, product specifications, website for ordering more, company website, warranty phone number, etc... I have considered parsing all of the retail websites for information but don't know the legalities behind it and if the websites change then I'd need to update code. If there is ANY (easier/better) way to do this then assistance or direction would be great!

Thanks always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not go down the route of trying to parse websites, that will be a huge pain in the neck and impossible to maintain unless you have extensive resources (and as you mention it probably violates most site's terms of service anyway). Your best bet would be to hook into existing product databases via an API, such as Google's Search API for shopping, or maybe Amazon's API. Here's where you can start if you wanted to use Google:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/

Hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.

**Edit:** Here's a list of a lot more shopping APIs that could be good options:

http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Shopping

Answer (score 1):

If you did find yourself needing to parse many different vendor websites (we'd call this "screen scraping") and you have the legal right to do so, you should use a tool like [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com) to get your XPaths, it's much faster, easier and less error-prone than doing it by hand.

If you're doing more than a couple websites, though, you'll probably find that you'll have to update the scraping rules pretty often, it definitely won't be a set-and-forget operation.